# How to show the picture box in front of textbox, combo box inside the Frame?

Tags: vb6

Using VB 6

Am using Frame, Inside that frame am using textbox, combo box, labels. 
When I am running the project it will show like "processing".
So I used the picuture box also inside that frame. But Picture box is not showing in the front of textbox, combobox, labels.

I tried, but it is showing only the picture layout, it is not showing the label “processing”

How to set a property for this condition.

Exactly i need, while executing the program it will show like processing then it will display a output.

Need VB 6 Help

Comment: I'm afraid this question is a bit difficult to understand. Can you try rewording it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A label component does not have a window handle -- hWnd, but instead is drawn right on its parent (in this case, the frame component it sounds like).

A combobox, a textbox, and a picturebox all have a window handle (hWnd), so can have a zOrder and appear behind/in front of other components.

I believe the answer to your question is to place the label component inside a picturebox, and then set the zOrder of the picturebox as needed.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your label is underneath one of the other controls (your question isn't particular clear) - if that is the case, you need to play with the ZOrder property of your controls to be able to decide which control gets to be on top (i.e. to be displayed). This [link](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=508387) gives you an example of how to use this property.

Comment: @jpoh. I modified my question.

Comment: +1. Here is a link to the VB6 documentation about ZOrder http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa267180(VS.60).aspx